# Send variable data to view

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to send the variable data to the view but I get the error:

> Undefined variable: total
>   below is the code from the controller:

```
public function show(Qualificationheader $qualificationheader)
{

    $qualificationheader = Qualificationheader::findOrFail($qualificationheader->id);

    $data = Information::where('curriculum_id','=',1)->first();
    $total = Information::where('curriculum_id','=',1)->sum('km_credits');

  // dd($total);
    return view('qualificationheaders.show', ['qualificationheader'=>$qualificationheader], ['information'=>$data],['total'=>$total]);
}
```

I've been under the impression that this:

`return view('qualificationheaders.show', ['qualificationheader'=>$qualificationheader], ['information'=>$data],['total'=>$total]);` would be enough to send a calculated value to the view

In the view: `{{$total}}`

What could I be doing wrong ? When I do dd on total, I get the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only pass in one array to the `view` helper:

```
return view('qualificationheaders.show', compact('qualificationheader', 'data', 'total'));
```

Or if you need to use specific variable names:

```
return view('qualificationheaders.show', [
    'qualificationheader' => $qualificationheader,
    'information' => $data,
    'total' => $total
]);
```